# Is it possible to block psexec without blocking regular SMB access?

Tags: windows, smb

I don't have much experience in protecting windows machines, so sorry if I'm missing something obvious; how would one protect from psexec without disabling SMB? One could disable the `admin$` share, but I've read here and there that it can cause some applications to misfunction. Is it something that can be handled by a local anti-virus? Sorry for the vagueness of my question, I have looked around but I wasn't able to find much. Thanks for any answer.

Edit for clarification: in short, I'd like to know whether it's possible to share data via SMB without allowing people to execute commands on my machine via psexec.

Comment: Are you using windows EMET?

Comment: @mootmoot I'm not asking about a specific use case, more in the general case. Does EMET block psexec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For psexec to work, you must already have local admin credentials for the target. If you don't want people using psexec to a given computer, the proper solution is to not give them admin rights there. Otherwise, they could just undo whatever you do anyway.

Comment: So a user without local admin rights can access a SMB share but not use psexec?

Comment: Right. SMB itself doesn't require local admin to use, but psexec does a lot of things that do.